# Use python to calculate a field by adding characters depending on length

Tags: python

How can I implement this in Python - I am trying to add a number of characters of a single letter (A) to an existing field in a table. Let us say the field is named "name", existing values can be xyz, ercd, we. Depending on the length of "name"
xyz becomes AAAAAXYZ (length of string is 3, the 5A are added in front)
ercd becomes AAAAercd (length of string is 4, the 4A are added in front)
we becomes AAAAAAwe (length of string is 2, the 6A are added in front)

Once the above is done the length of "name" is always 8.

My current work flow is to populate another field with the length of "name" and use that to determine the number of A, to be concatenated.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Check the Stack Overflow's [help on asking questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) first, please. Focus on [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask), [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and [Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist).

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you want to [rjust](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.rjust):

```
>>> name = 'xyz'
>>> name.rjust(8, 'A')
'AAAAAxyz'
>>> 'ercd'.rjust(8, 'A')
'AAAAercd'
>>>
```